# Kotlin - println using string template to stderr

Tags: kotlin

How do I send output of `println()` to `System.err`.  I want to use *string template*.

```
val i = 3
println("my number is $i")
```

`println()` sends *message* to stdout and it looks like there is no option to send to stderr.

Comment: I should have been clear.  I wanted to use string template.

Comment: string interpolation is not limited to the `println` function, but works everywhere in kotlin.

Answer (score 32):

Kotlin unfortunately does not provide ubiquitous way to write to `stderr`.

If you target **JVM with Kotlin** you can use the same API as in Java.

```
System.err.println("Hello standard error!")
```

In case of **Kotlin Native** you can use a function that opens the stderr and writes to it manually with the use of `platform.posix` package.

```
val STDERR = platform.posix.fdopen(2, "w")
fun printErr(message: String) {
    platform.posix.fprintf(STDERR, "%s\n", message)
    platform.posix.fflush(STDERR)
}

printErr("Hello standard error!")
```

**Note**: Using formatting function `printf` may have security implications. [Format string vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack) can crash your application and you may want to consider using [`_s` "secure" variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-170) of printf function.

---

In multi-platform projects one can use mechanism of `expect` and `actual` function to provide single interface to write to STDERR on all platforms.

```kotlin
// Common
expect fun eprintln(string: String): void

// JVM
actual fun eprintln(string: String) = System.err.println(string)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html

Comment: Shouldn't you do `fprintf(STDERR, "%s\n", message)` to avoid having a format string vulnerability?

Comment: @Mendess While the original code was just an example (and did not even compile without changes), I added a section about security. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In a **Kotlin JS** there is no stderr generally (for both Browser and Node targets), but we can use `console.error(message)` as a potential implementation.

Answer (score 9):

You can just do it like you would in Java:

```
System.err.println("hello stderr")
```

The standard stdout output just gets the special shorter version via some helper methods in Kotlin because it's the most often used output. You could use that with the full `System.out.println` form too.

Comment: Mostly goes without saying, but this doesn't help with other Kotlin platforms, e.g. native.

Comment: The question is from 2017, and it asks specifically about the JVM, writing to `System.err`.

Answer (score 5):

why not create a global function

```
fun printErr(errorMsg:String){
   System.err.println(errorMsg)
}
```

then call it from anyware

```
printErr("custom error with ${your.custom.error}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print error as like Java in Kotlin then check the below code:

```
System.err.println("Printing Error")
```

It will print it in red color.

But if you use just only `println()` then it will work like:

```
System.out.println("Printing Hello")
```

Comment: Same issue as some other answers above: this does not work in Kotlin native. Kotlin != Kotlin/JVM